# onReceive function not working to identify a particular phone number through my app

Tags: android

I created a class called `PhoneCallReciever.java` which extends `BroadcastReceiver`
Anytime a user calls, a Toast should appear which is defined in `CallReceiver.java`. However this is not happening and there is no data being logged as well

**PhoneCallReceiver.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telecom.Call;
import android.telecom.TelecomManager;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Date;

public abstract class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Entered onReceive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        } else {
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;
            if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }


            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }

    //Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
    protected abstract void onIncomingCallReceived(Context ctx, String number, Date start);

    protected abstract void onIncomingCallAnswered(Context ctx, String number, Date start);

    protected abstract void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end);

    protected abstract void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start);

    protected abstract void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end);

    protected abstract void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start);

    //Deals with actual events

    //Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
    //Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
        if (lastState == state) {
            //No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                savedNumber = number;
                onIncomingCallReceived(context, number, callStartTime);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
                if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    isIncoming = false;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                } else {
                    isIncoming = true;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onIncomingCallAnswered(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }

                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                    onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                } else if (isIncoming) {
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                } else {
                    onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }
}
```

**CallReceiver.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Date;

public class CallReceiver extends PhoneCallReceiver {

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallReceived(Context ctx, String number, Date start)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Incoming Call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallAnswered(Context ctx, String number, Date start)
    {
        //
    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end)
    {
        //
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start)
    {
        //
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end)
    {
        //
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.xxxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".DialogBoxActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LocationActivity" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The first thing I'd do is log `state` and `incomingNumber` to see if anything's coming in... if not, you need to look into why not (e.g. permissions).

Comment: are you checking in marshmallow device? if so did you ask for run time permissions?

Comment: @sravs no it is a one plus 3 with the latest Nougat version