# Change a single Firebase value based on the query of another value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase Database looks like this

[image]

I wish to change the `event_user_image` value by querying the data and comparing the value of `event_username`. 
My code looks like this

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference dr = database.getReference().child("ApprovedEvents");
        dr.orderByChild("event_user_name").equalTo("username");
        dr.child("event_user_image").setValue("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/photo.jpg");
```

Instead it makes a separate value  under Approved Events.
Please help !

Comment: Could you post the code that you used to do initial push of data into database.

Comment: @TheManHasNoName The initial push is done by another Admin app. I don't believe that is required

Comment: When you perform database.getReference().child("ApprovedEvents"); you are at the root of ApprovedEvents, but instead if you do some thing like database.getReference().child("ApprovedEvents").child("UserDetails"), and store the values related to username and image inside it, only then you can specifically access those values. Other wise you will need the unique key generated to access that column which I believe is practically not possible

Comment: If you can't do the above,You might need to get snapshot("Approved Events"), and then iterate through each children, then you will be able to update user images accordingly. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#public-methods

Comment: @TheManHasNoName How do iterate through the list of ApprovedEvents by matching `event_username` with "username" value.

Comment: May be this could help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37508782/how-to-iterate-over-a-datasnapshot-without-specifying-parent-folder-ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DatabaseReference is referring to **ApprovedEvents** and when you set the value for **event_user_image**, it would have it like this:

```
ApprovedEvents
---Record 1
---Record 2
.
.
.
---event_user_image
```

What you want to do is change the **event_user_image** for a specific record.

To do that, you first have to query the record with the specific username like this:

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference dr = database.getReference().child("ApprovedEvents");
Query query = dr.orderByChild("username").equalTo("yourUsername");
```

Then you could use a listener to see if there would be objects queried with that specific username then get their keys so you could add it in the path for updating:

```
query.addChildEventListener(
        new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                //dr would refer to path                  : ApprovedEvents
                //adding the key as a child would make it : ApprovedEvents/Record1
                dr.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("event_user_image").setValue("yourDesiredValue");
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Could you please help me with this problem as well 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/43020091/6599112